# Hash Function Overflow

Tags: data-structures, hash

In my class of data structure we are learning different hash functions, but this one in particular I do not understand why in the last three lines of the code they check if HashVal<0, because since HashVal is the reminder of division for tableSize it should never be less than zero. Please I just want to understand this last part. Thank you in advance.

```
public static int hash(String key, int tableSize)

{

int hashVal = 0;

for( int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++ )

  hashVal = 37 * hashVal + key.charAt(i);

hashVal %= tableSize;

if( hashVal < 0 ) //overflow case

   hashVal += tableSize;

return hashVal;
```

}

Comment: hashVal is a int, and it might overflow to become a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hashVal is a int, and it has a maximum size.
If the length of the string is long enough, the hashVal becomes really big because you've multiplied it by 37 for many times, and it overflows.
When it overflows, it might become a negative number, so you need to check the result if hashVal is negative.

There is also a known way to solve this.
Change

```
for( int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++ )
  hashVal = 37 * hashVal + key.charAt(i);
  hashVal %= tableSize;
```

into

```
for( int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++ ) {
   hashVal = 37 * hashVal + key.charAt(i);
   hashVal %= tableSize;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! And with the way you changed  the for loop is not necessary to check for an overflow right?

Comment: Using long **with** the for loop might help. I guess that the module result * 37 might still overflow if the tableSize is big enough. BTW, the answer by @Artem describes the reason why integers are overflowing.

Answer (score 2):

int in Java is signed [32-bit data type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Therefore, maximum value which it can store is [2^31-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit#Range_for_storing_integers) which is [MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) constant in Integer class. Based on [negative number representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) (left bit is a sign bit) once a number is more than MAX_VALUE it will become negative based on that representation.